# How can I change all links to river-valley.tv?

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, hyperlinks

I have recorded many videos of conferences, including TeX conferences. For nearly 10 years I have been hosting these on www.river-valley.tv. The domain is now not under my control (long story), and the DNS has been changed, so the videos are inaccessible. I have transferred all videos to "zeeba.tv", so any links will now work by adding "zeeba" before ".tv".

There are a lot of backlinks to ".tv" on StackExchange, in TeX-related questions. Is there any way of adding "zeeba" to all these, or at least alerting to viewers about the domain change?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is no automated way of doing this from your end. However, you can [refine your search](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/searching) on the main/meta site to identify posts which have the now-defunct URL using the search query [`url:"river-valley.tv"`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3A%22river-valley.tv%22). This reveals only 24 posts:

[image]

My suggestion would be to visit each post sequentially over the next couple of days (say 5 posts a day) and you'll be done within a week with the URL updates. The slowed updating process avoids the [home page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/) from being flooded by old posts - it lists "active" posts, which include those that has undergone a revision of some sort. As such, there's no real problem with doing it manually.

The only [four posts](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3A%22river-valley.zeeba.tv%22) on [Meta.TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com) have already been updated (thanks @barbarabeeton):

[image]

Comment: [Last time we had to bump loads of posts](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5659/what-should-be-done-about-the-size-tag/5670#5670), we seemed to have been fine with two dozens a day, so I think they could be all done in one day.